# Flutter - how to expand a container in a row to make it fit to a container on next row?

Tags: flutter, layout, flexbox

I ask for you help with layouting in Flutter with Flex and Expand widgets.
I've made simple example to show what I want and what I get.

My purpose is to create column with 2 rows. Each row should have 2 blocks.
Blocks #2 should be on the same left position.

[image: This is what I want to get.]

**1) This is my code for Column & Rows:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
              child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                    child: Text("Short", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amberAccent),
                    child: Text("Text-2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
              ])),
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
              child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                    child: Text("Long block", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amberAccent),
                    child: Text("Text-2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
              ])),
        ]);
```

This is what I get:
[image]

**2) This is my code for Flex:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: <
        Widget>[
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
          child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Flex(
                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                          child: Text("Short", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))
                    ]),
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amberAccent),
                    child: Text("Text-2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
              ])),
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
          child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                    child: Text("Long block", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amberAccent),
                    child: Text("Text-2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
              ])),
    ]);
```

This is what I get with Flex:
[image: This is what I get with Flex]

**3) This is my code for Expanded:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: <
        Widget>[
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
          child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                        child: Text("Short", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amberAccent),
                    child: Text("Text-2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
              ])),
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
          child: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                    child: Text("Long block", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amberAccent),
                    child: Text("Text-2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
              ])),
    ]);
```

This is what I get with Expanded:
[image: This is what I get with Expanded]

Please, help me make the right widgets hierarchy to get what is on the first picture.
Thanks!

Comment: Is your requirement to use this type of layout ? You can obtain what you want if you use one row with two columns inside it, instead of one column with two rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps me with my example.

Comment: In my real task I have one row for one record from my database. Of course I can solve it with Row - Columns hierarchy. But I want to learn how to stretch a container like on my first picture. In HTML + CSS I can use div(flex-direction: column) - 2 divs (flex-direction: row) - div (flex-grow: 1) & div (without flex-grow).

Comment: To have a grid, use a Table.  That'll make rows be deep enough for the tallest item, and columns wide enough for the largest item in the column.

Comment: Randal Schwartz, thanks a lot. Table works perfectly. Also I wrapped it into Flex and used "defaultColumnWidth: IntrinsicColumnWidth()" for squeezing it.